# How can I adjust distance between text and image when using multicols?

Tags: graphics, multicol

`\textfloatsep`, `\floatsep` and `\intextsep` seem not to work when using `multicols`.

Is there a different way to set the distances before and after an image when using multicols?

Comment: Can you post a MWE for your requirement?

Comment: you can not use floats at  all in multicols, and if you are including images just via `\includegraphics{...}` then no space is added, so there are no lengths to set.

Comment: What is a MWE? Sorry, I'm new here

Comment: I am currently inserting the images as 
`\begin{center}

 \includegraphics[width=.26\textwidth]{crossoverT.jpg}

\end{center}`

since `\begin{figure}` did not work with the multicols.
The problem is that I need to reduce the used space to the maximum, I need it for a summary to bring to an exam.

Comment: Doesn't \vspace{amountofspace}work?; example \vspace{-2em} just before the image

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work. The text either overlap the image or the space remained unchanged depending on the value. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
% !TeX TS-encoding = utf8
% !TeX TS-spellcheck = fr_FR
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\fig}[2][.26]{{\hfill\includegraphics[width=#1\linewidth]{#2}\hfill}\break}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \fig{Image}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

## Edit

As pointed out by @Frank Mittelbach, my first atempt was lacking `multicol`…
I also took into account @David's comment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\fig}[2][.26]{{\par\centering\includegraphics[width=#1\linewidth]{#2}\par}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[1]
        \fig{Image}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\break` in that way will generate underfull box if there is a paragraph break, also the outer group does nothing as `\includegraphics` makes no visible assignments. better to simply have `{{\par\centering\includegraphics[..]{..}\par}}`

Comment: I found a different solution, but if it gives me other problems in future I'll try it out.
The current solution is:
`{\centering \includegraphics[width=.26\textwidth]{crossoverT.jpg}}`, which is similar to David's solution, but without \par to save some more space.

Comment: @Nico but without `\par` `\centering` does nothing.

Comment: where is multicol in your solution which is what the question was about?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help!

I used the following code:

`{\centering \includegraphics[width=.12\textwidth]{ImageName.jpg}}`

eventually, depending on where the image is:

`{\centering \includegraphics[width=.12\textwidth]{ImageName.jpg}\\}`

Which is basically:

`{\par\centering \includegraphics[width=.12\textwidth]{ImageName.jpg}\par}` without `\par` to save some more space.

Comment: Omitting the `\par` is wrong, or at least if you are going to omit `\par` you need to omit `\centering` as well , using `\\ ` at the end will only work if there is text immediately afterwards,  otherwise the paragraph will end with `\\ ` and you will get underfull box errors and a spurious white line. It is _far better_  to end with `\par` as I  showed. By default `\par`  adds no vertical space.

Comment: better anyway to use \begin{center} ... \end{center} as that gives you some space (they typical list amount) and also avoids issue with centering not acting if you don't have \par in the right place